# Apache Parquet for flat data structures

Tags: hadoop, parquet

> Parquet is built from the ground up with complex nested data structures in mind, and uses the record shredding and assembly algorithm described in the Dremel paper.

I'm aware that the support of nested structures is a must for a general-purpose storage format. However, it seems that the overhead of the record shredding and assembly (and additional storage for definition and repetition levels probably) is redundant in case of flat data.

Is the overhead negligible? Are there any alternative columnar storage formats available?

Comment: Maybe a better approach is to provide some example flatten data and discuss why that is overhead to use parquet.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue the benefits of just having a structured filetype is better than the alternative of plaintext, whether or not there's algorithms supported by that using that format.

XML files can have a schema, but are too verbose, and don't contain such columnar statistics like Parquet.

ORC, RCFile, and RecordIO are alternative columnar formats for storage.

Apache Arrow is an in-memory columnar format